# Hibernate 5.2 Native Query with void function Postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, nativequery

I'm a beginner with hibernate. 
I have a void function in PostgreSQL with 10 arguments (it's a "create or update" function) and I want to use it in my application.

I read that doing a Native Query is the simplest way.

So I wrote this code:

```java
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

String a = "SELECT fun('text', 'text', 12345678987, 'text', 'text', 50, 37500, 133456788, 'text', 2);
session.createNativeQuery(a);

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

The application starts without any errors, but when I check the database I don't have new record.

Can someone explain what is wrong? Should I do something else with the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`When I check database I don't have new rekord`
Ofc you don't, you are doing a `SELECT`, so you're not doing anything in your database.

Also in order to execute your query you don't need to open any transaction since you are not inserting/updating/deleting anything, and you need to do the following to get the result:

`session.createNativeQuery(a).getResultList()` if you expect multiple results from this query

`session.createNativeQuery(a).getSingleResult()` if you expect only one result.

`session.createNativeQuery(a).executeUpdate()` if you're actually inserting/updating/deleting something, in that case you will need the transaction like you did in your code.

Comment: But i was write that is function (there is INSERT in function so i should have new record). 

It's void function są i should get only one (void) result so i use getSingleRecord(). Now i have MappingError
```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

Comment: That error means that the type returned from your query isn't supported

Comment: One question: does your function "fun" return something? Because if it doesn't, that means your select statement will never return anything.

Comment: My function is declared to be returned void "... RETURNS void AS $$ ..."
Is it possible that hibernate don't support this?

Comment: I decided change returned value on integer. Now it's work correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `session.createNativeQuery(a)` it will create a query but it will not execute it until you call `executeUpdate()` method of native query.

Comment: I used getSingleResult() like vc73 wrote earlier because my function return only void. 

But now i have org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111  and I still don't know what is wrong.